# Exporting Layer Attribute Table Fields To CSV using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, csv

I would like to export the names of all the attribute table field names of all the layers in my QGIS document to a spreadsheet, I know I need to loop through an array of the layers, the field names in the layers, and then export, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

Could someone provide an example of such a script?

[image]

Comment: @PolyGeo: why did you close the question?

Comment: @eurojam This site's custom close reason for closing questions lacking a code snippet came about in https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3994/115.  It is designed to prevent GIS SE being seen as a code request service.  We have many non-programmers on this site, and for our spatial programmers to answer all their requests for code is likely to exhaust their desire to volunteer.  Closing does nothing other than prevent additional answers.  As long as either the question or answer receives upvotes they will remain on the site forever.

Comment: @PolyGeo. In this case, it may be better to divide the questions into 1) information questions; 2) questions related to coding; 3) questions related to data transformation (re-projection); 4) questions related to geo-processing of data, etc.?

Comment: @Cyril I’m not sure what you are asking me. When reviewing questions I first informally classify them into one of many question types and structures, and then I apply any answers/votes/edits/comments on the basis of which category they fall in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following script writes all fields from vector layers into a CSV file. Perhaps you have to make some changes, it is just a quick idea how to start:

```
import csv
group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
layers = [ item.layer() for item in group ] #list of all layers
for layer in layers:
    if layer.type()==0: #check if layertype is vector
        fields = [ field.name() for field in layer.fields() ] #list of all fields
        print (layer.name(),fields) #print it to the console
        with open('d:/test.csv', 'a') as myfile: # export it to csv
            wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            wr.writerow(fields)
```

Save the script to a file.py and open it from the Python console->Editor