# Export only specific fields of a QGIS layer as CSV

Tags: python, attribute-table, fields-attributes, export, csv

I have some layers that contain attachments (photos and videos). The layers have the following attributes:
`['ATTACHMENTID', 'GLOBALID', 'REL_GLOBALID', 'CONTENT_TYPE', 'ATT_NAME', 'DATA_SIZE', 'DATA']`
The attachments are stored in the `DATA` field.
I want to export the attribute table as CSV except the `DATA` field, as it inflates the field and contains no useful information.
I used the following code:

```
def save_layer_as_csv(layer, save_path, save_name):
    '''Solutions from:https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/373856/95891
                  and:https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348457/95891'''

    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,f'{save_path}/{save_name}.csv',
    "utf-8",driverName = "CSV" , layerOptions = ['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'])
```

This code exports all the fields which are not needed.
I found a good post [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/343626/95891) that exports only one field of the layer by adding `attributes=[idx], onlySelected=True` to the line above, but I don't know how to slice the fields as object and add them to the `attribute` parameter!

I tried to slice using the `layer.fields()[:-1]` code, but it returned an error `argument 1 has unexpected type 'slice'`

How can I solve this issue to export all the fields except the last one?

> Note: I use QGIS 3.26.2-Buenos Aires

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct indices' list.

```
fields = ['ATTACHMENTID', 'GLOBALID', 'REL_GLOBALID',
          'CONTENT_TYPE', 'ATT_NAME', 'DATA_SIZE'] 
idxs = [layer.fields().indexFromName(f) for f in fields]
```

And use `attributes=idxs` instead of `attributes=[idx]` as parameter.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, you made a generalizable answer. However, I would like to add a clarification that I did not know before your answer. the `attributes=` accepts a list of numbers, not a list of fields object, i.e., my problem could be solved by adding `attributes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to the CSV writing statement.

Answer (score 6):

`layer.fileds()` returns a `QgsFields` object, not a list. If you need to omit the last field, use this:

```
idxs = list(range(len(layer.fields())- 1))
```

And use `attributes=idxs`.